# XGBoost: Convert dmatrix into a numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, xgboost

I'd like to inspect the `DMatrix` object. The [documentation mentions](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.DMatrix) the methods to get the number of rows and columns and also the slice at each row:

```
dmatrix.slice(index)
```

But I'd like to do more complex transformations using numpy. Is there a simple way to convert the `DMatrix` to a numpy array?

Comment: It seems there is not such a simple way. For example, take a look at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1668.

Comment: Thanks! I like the way the maintainers handled this

Comment: actually, it is possible by dmatrix2np package, and also can see the code here:
https://github.com/aporia-ai/dmatrix2np

Answer (score 2):

DMatrix is a one-way street! Once you get DMatrix, you cannot get back its content as `numpy.ndarray` or `pandas.DataFrame`.

[Update] A library is implemented only for the particular task of convert XGBoost's DMatrix format to `numpy.array`: https://github.com/aporia-ai/dmatrix2np

Comment: @el_Rinaldo yet, someone did not like my answer 

Comment: actually that was sarcasm. Giving you a thumb up, anyway. I'm sure that's not a decision of yours :)

Comment: So, is there a way? Check https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1668 or https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1462